# How to carry session value from one page to another in php?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I want to  carry value stored in session one page to another page  where I am using  following code which value I want to carry it is not working.

Here is my code

**login.php**

```
<?php

include('conn.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $UserName=$_POST['user'];
    $PassWord=$_POST['pass'];
    $eid=$_POST['eid'];
    //echo $UserName;
    //echo $PassWord;
    $sql = "SELECT role from login WHERE username='$UserName'and password='$PassWord'";
    //$sql=mysql_query("select usertype from login where username='$UserType' and password='$Password'")or die (mysql_error());//query sang database 
    $retval = mysql_query($sql);

    if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        session_start();

        $_SESSION["user"]=$UserName;
        $_SESSION["pass"]=$PassWord ;
        $_SESSION['role']=$row['role'];
        $_SESSION['eid']=$eid;

        if ($row['role']==0) {
            header("location:admin.php");
        }
        elseif ($row['role']==1) {
            header("location:UserUomePage.php");
        }
    } 
}

echo "Invalid User Name and Password\n";

?>
```

When I use

```
 echo $_SESSION['eid'];
```

it is giving user name.  How can I get eid value?

Comment: Check the value in the $eid variable maybe?

Comment: Please use proper code intendation. It seeas you're calling `session_start` multiple times within your `while`loop.

Comment: i checked there also but not

Comment: If you are using sessions, you likely should just start at the beginning of your script, not within a conditional and DEFINITELY not within a loop contruct. You are also going to be overwrintig your session values with each pass through the loop. You shoiuld probably just build the array of row data the way you want and then set the compiled array to session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep session_start() outside the loop.
And check are you getting value from post in $eid or not.
In next page, you can check:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

and see what values you are getting.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['eid']))
{
 echo $_SESSION['eid'];
}
else
   echo 'NO';
```

Comment: please share what u getting in print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: i a getting this

Array ( [user] => satyam [pass] => satyam [role] => 1 [eid] => )

Comment: it means u not getting value of eid from $_POST
Please also try to print $_POST in above code at first line
print_r($_POST);